# Unity - get position of UI Slider Handle

Tags: unity-game-engine, uislider

I am working on Unity 4.7 project and need to create shooting on the target. I simulated gunpoint using horizontal and vertical slider moving on the time. When I click the button I need to memorize x and y coordinates of handles and instantiate bullet hole at this point but don't know how to get cords of sliders handle. It is possible to get values but it seems that it doesn't correspond to coordinates. If horizontal slider changes its value for 1, would its handle change x position for 1?

Comment: do you need the world space or screen space coords of the handle ?

Comment: There is an image of target (10 radial circles) behind the sliders. I want to instantiate bullet hole image at the point of crossing handles. I dont know what type of cords I need.

Comment: are all the object in the UI ? This would make them in screen space.

Comment: Yes, all of the objects are in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this then:

```
    public static Vector3 GetScreenPositionFromWorldPosition(Vector3 targetPosition)
    {
        Vector3 screenPos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(targetPosition);
        return screenPos;
    }
```

Have the reference to Handles of the horizontal and vertical sliders, and use them like:

```
Vector3 pos = GetScreenPositionFromWorldPosition(horizontalHandle.transform.position);
```